# Why does an extra symbol get created when I import a png file into Flash CS3?

Tags: flash, png

When I import a .png file into the library in Flash CS3, I noticed that the system always creates an extra symbol in the library. If I import, for example, foo.png, into the library, it not only creates a bitmap with the same name, but also a Symbol of the type "Graphic" with the default name, e.g. Symbol 576.

I am not using these symbols in the flash movie, only the .png itself, and it works just fine (the png gets displayed, even with transparency).

I'm curious about:
-why these additional symbols get created?
-do they serve any purpose? (i.e. can I delete them or does that impede the functionality of displaying the images somehow?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly sure they just get created as a convenience to the developer. You can delete them without any issue (I do it all the time myself).

Comment: it does not answer all the points in the question but it looks like there will be no alternative answer for this